# How do we go about imbalanced data for prediction problem?

Tags: regression, prediction, class-imbalance

As in classification we have imbalanced classes, we use up-sampling or down-sampling and other techniques, what do we do when we have imbalanced data in prediction problems, for example, I have distribution of outputs like 90% value1, 5% value2, 3%value3, 2% value4?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to post linked by @Wes:

- You should to check other metrics                than accuracy like
  precision, recall (especially), F1 score or similar.
- After a certain threshold (lower than the one provided in your
  example definitely), it might be worthwile to use anomaly detection
  and use your lesser present classes as such.

I would advise against downsampling as it's leaving informations about data, and IMO you would usually want to avoid that.